# Java: Type Safety warning with unchecked conversion

Tags: java, eclipse, warnings

I am using java in my project. When I try to get keys from a json object I get this warning: `Type safety: The expression of type Iterator needs unchecked conversion to conform to Iterator` I tried to fix by `@SupressWarning('unchecked')` but eclipse still shows the warning on file. I don't know what is going wrong.

```
   public static HashMap<String, String> jsonToMap(final JSONObject jsonMap)
                throws JSONException {
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
            Iterator<Object> keys = jsonMap.keys();
            while (keys.hasNext()) {
                String key = (String) keys.next();
                String value = jsonMap.getString(key);
                map.put(key, value);

            }
            return map;
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters, The warning won't hurt you. It's just a heads up.
Also, make sure you have the syntax right.  It should be:

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")  (you can place at the method level or right above the line you want to suppress.

Secondly,  It's probably important to understand what the code is doing, because what you have works, but it reads a little oddly.

The warning basically says you have an iterator of an unknown type and you're assuming that it's an Iterator of Objects.

Then later in your code you cast all the keys to strings. You might as well just create an Iterator of Strings instead and skip the cast.

```
Iterator<String> keys = jsonMap.keys();
        while (keys.hasNext()) {
            String key = keys.next();
            String value = jsonMap.getString(key);
            map.put(key, value);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

`JSONObject#Keys()` method returns `Iterator` of raw type and you're trying to assign it to reference of `Iterator<Object>`. Refer [JSONObject](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html#keys()).